# how to load files into github repository

Tags: git, bash, github

Hi I am new to git hub: I did it in the past but now  do not know how to do it.
I created a repository 'https://github.com/kobosh/everyonehub' public it contains only readme file ;now i want to add my visual studio  messageboards project     which lives in  c:\users\aouf\messageboards

I have tried open bash command and cd to users/aouf/messageboards
then git add messageboards
git commit -m "7/2 from comnd"
it seems this went alright I got message 7 files changed .....etc 
Then I typed git remote add origin https:/github.com/kobosh/everyonehub
I got message fatal remote origin already exists....
please help me with this first step: how to add my project files to my git hub repo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you cloned the 'empty' repository from github (with a `git clone`). The remote already is your github' distant repository. Just use `git push origin master` to transfer your changes to github' servers.

You have 2 choices.

**1st one:**

`Copy/Past` your files into the cloned folder (`c:\users\aouf\messageboards`). `git push origin master`

**2nd one:**

`cd` in your local project folder, `git init`, and `git remote add origin https:/github.com/kobosh/everyonehub`. Commit, Push, and everything will be ok!

You can [take a look here](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-push) if you want to read the official documentation.

Comment: not quiet! I see no files in my repo!!!! I git push origin master.....then user name /password....got message everything up to date but I see no files in repo

Comment: Follow this lead :

**1.** `cd c:\users\aouf\messageboards`
**2.** `git init`
**3.** `git remote add origin https:/github.com/kobosh/everyonehub`
**4.** `git add .`
**5.** `git commit -m "7/2 from comnd"`
**6.** `git push origin master`

Answer (score 0):

You've added the files, the remote exists already, now you just need to push the files.
http://git-scm.com/docs/git-push

```
git push origin master
```